# what to do when Heroku down?

Tags: heroku

Today my app on Heroku down and I can do nothing about it.

Just wait for Heroku engineers to fix it and feel helpless.

Are there other ways around to fix this problem? something like a back-up hosting somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every host is going to have down time - I'm 100% happy hosting on Heroku since I know that there will always be people paying them way more than I do and will be shouting much louder than I can to get the platform back up.